# javac cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have root-like this

```
├── appointment
└── src
    └── main
         └── java
               └── com
                    └── sendemail
                             ├── MainAppointment.java
                             └── SendMail.java
```

All is working and compiled as expected by running via the IDE(IntelliJ).
by running javac MainAppointment.java from other then the sendemail package the files are not found while running the javac MainAppointment.java command from the sendemail directory cannot find symbol error is returned

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You should learn to build your projects with maven.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. For example, show us the exact javac command you're using and the error message  it produces.

Comment: Hi, the javac command I executed is javac com/sendemail/MainAppointment.java  and the error is :

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to compile by hand, you should not run `javac` in any directory other than your source directory; i.e. the one that contains the top-level package(s) as direct subdirectories.  That means you will need to do something like this:

```
  $ cd appointment/src/main/java
  $ javac com/sendemail/MainAppointment.java com/sendemail/SendMail.java
```

<sup>(OK it might be possible to do it using the `-sourcepath` and `-cp` and `-d` options but it is messy.  But either way, you may develop RSI from all of the typing.  Not to mention the time you waste looking for "bugs" that are actually caused by not building correctly; e.g. this one!)</sup>

A better idea is to learn to a build tool.  It looks like this project has been set up with the standard Maven project structure.  (Is there a "pom.xml" file in the "appointment" directory?)  So Maven would probably be the tool to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't help the returned error is :
javac: file not found: com/sendemail/SendMail.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

yes I have pom.xml file by running the mvn clean install command it building the project (jar is created) but it is not executing the commands in the code

Comment: 1)  Did you `cd` to the directory above "com"?  Can you see the 2 Java files with the those relative paths?  2) *"... but it is not executing the commands in the code"* - that sounds like a different problem; i.e. a bug in your code.

Comment: yes, the directory was appointment/src/main/java, I can see them both under those relative paths

Comment: Well I cannot explain why `javac com/sendemail/MainAppointment.java com/sendemail/SendMail.java` does not work for you.   Look at https://riptutorial.com/java/example/15658/the--javac--command---getting-started ... and search for `javac com/example/*.java`.  That is analogous to what I said to you.

Comment: (It is also possible that the `cannot find symbol` is caused by something else; e.g. a problem with the classpath, or an error in the code you are trying to compile.)